# Changing the min. SDK version of an Android app 2

Tags: android, sdk, version, min

I work withe android open source Bluetooth project & I like to use Holo theme series  but sdk min version is 6  when I change this version to higher version in my test device return error :unfortunately , app name has stopped
here is my source url : https://github.com/polyclef/BluetoothChatMulti

excuse Because  of my bad English

Comment: "unfortunately , app name has stopped" is very generic error message. Can you please provide us with some stack trace and code snippet

Comment: I now ,but if you can check yours by git link, I'm basic programmer

Comment: Nowadays, anything below minSdkVersion="8" is outdated (less than 0.1% of the global market).

Comment: i have run your code and app working fine but it show not connected in top right corner.

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions of Android, the framework will use the `Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR` feature whenever the Holo theme is selected. 
The framework throws the exception whenever an app calls setFeatureInt(`Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE`) and `FEATURE_ACTION_BAR` has already been set.

In my case, the styles.xml file in the values-v11 folder was redefining my theme to inherit from `android:Theme.Holo`. When I attempted to run my app on a *Android 3.0 or above* - it crashed because *Holo uses the ActionBar* by default. The fix was simple. Turn the `ActionBar` off when using `Holo.` Here is the revised *values-v11\styles.xml* changes:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.NoActionBar">
    <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>
```

and for higer versions we can't combine custom titles or other title features